# Linux Terminal - Can anyone break down this echo command?

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently trying to complete the overthewire bandit levels. I got stuck on a level that wanted me to decode a .txt file that had been encrypted into ROT13. I looked online for answers came upon one that worked. I copied and pasted it into my terminal and moved on. However, I didn't actually understand what I had just done. The code will be below if anyone can explain it to me. Thanks!

```
echo "Enter text here" | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'
```

Comment: Try reading the manual entries for `echo` and `tr`.  That will give you the insight you need.  Assuming you know what `|` does!

Comment: Helpful link [man 1 tr]((https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) where you have both *SET1* and *SET2*.

Answer (score 2):

`echo`: write arguments to the standard output
`tr`: copies the standard input to the standard output with substitution or deletion of selected characters.

`|` pipes the output as input to next command

`tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'` : the first arg of tr describes the input pattern. Registers all characters lower and upper case. The second arg describes the output pattern. In this case, substitute (transliterate)

'A' -> 'N'

'B' -> 'O'

'C' -> 'P'

... -> ...

'L' -> 'Z'

here, we reached z, so we "go back to 'A'".

'M' -> 'A'

'N' -> 'B'

... -> ...

The same goes for the lower case characters. I recommend you try:
`echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | tr '[A-Za-z]' '[N-ZA-Mn-za-m]'` to see a pattern clearly.